# Apache on Last Logins list

Tags: linux, login

I have set the apache user to have /sbin/nologin as his shell, but still he appears many times in the list of last logins (`last` command) - probably by someone who I surely didn't want to do so.

What am I missing here, what else can trigger an entry on the last logins list? Obviously he was able to login without a shell?!

Here are some of the entries, in case that helps.

```
root     pts/0        xx     Sat Feb 20 13:36   still logged in   
apache   pts/0        xx     Fri Feb 19 01:20 - 01:20  (00:00)    
apache   pts/0        xx     Mon Feb 15 08:57 - 08:57  (00:00)    
apache   pts/0        xx     Wed Feb 10 22:23 - 22:23   (00:00)    
root     pts/0        xx     Sun Feb  7 17:27 - 03:40  (10:13)    
apache   pts/0        xx     Sat Feb  6 16:53 - 16:53  (00:00)    
root     pts/0        xx     Tue Feb  2 18:39 - 18:53  (00:13)    
root     pts/0        xx     Tue Feb  2 18:24 - 18:36  (00:12)    
apache   pts/0        xx     Mon Feb  1 22:48 - 22:48  (00:00)    
apache   pts/0        xx     Mon Feb  1 22:47 - 22:47  (00:00)    
apache   pts/0        xx     Mon Feb  1 22:47 - 22:47  (00:00)    
apache   pts/0        xx     Mon Feb  1 03:09 - 03:09  (00:00)
```

Also I have noticed that someone has tried a whole lot of other accounts (httpd, apache2, httpd2, httpdocs, etc...), which (of course) all failed. The list of failed logins is not long enough for a brute force though, so I'm wondering how he was able to enter in the end...

Thanks for any hints in advance

Comment: Please show us some relevant entries.

Comment: @lain there you go, hope that helps

Comment: Is it possible those login-times correspond to Apache service-restarts?

Comment: @sysadmin1138 I don't see any apache restarts in the error_log

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: @crnlx Centos 6.something

Comment: What's the output of this? cat /etc/passwd | grep apache

Comment: I got to go, so just posted an answer, let me know here if that helps.

Comment: @crnlx sorry, was afk. The user is set up to use the nologin shell, login frequency is pretty random. There are a few failed logins though from apache, apache2, httpd, httpd2, httpdocs and so on. See my updated question please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36022/discussion-between-crnlx-and-yorrd).

Answer (score 1):

This answer is also meant for others who may come across this thread looking for some tips, especially if auditing and notifications have not been set up.

## Have you restricted the user from logging in?

```
grep apache /etc/passwd
```

Check for `/bin/false` or `/usr/sbin/nologin` or `/sbin/nologin` at the end of the entry for the user.

## History of unsuccessful login attempts

```
lastb apache
```

This will show you the number of unsuccessful attempts to login by the user apache. 
(The output of `lastb` shows the log entries from `/var/log/btmp`, whereas `last` shows the entries of `/var/log/wtmp`)

## Login frequency and times

Check the output of `last`. Does the user log in at random times? Or does it happen at a specific time everyday?

## Failed logins and IPs

```
grep 'apache' /var/log/auth.log
```

Since you said there were failed login attempts, `/var/log/auth.log` should have the IP addresses from which those login attempts occurred (via SSH). Look especially for the last unsuccessful attempts made just before the first successful login attempt. The latter can be found by checking the output of `last` vs that of `lastb`. You can also compare log entries in `/var/log/btmp` against those in `/var/log/wtmp`.